# Unable to debug with following error: "Unable to attach to CoreCLR. A debug component is not installed."

Tags: winui-3, coreclr, windows-app-sdk

If I create a new project with "Blank App, Packaged (WinUI 3 in Desktop)", replace `<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>` of `App1.csproj` with `<TargetFramework>net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>`, and start debugging, the following error occurs.

Unable to attach to CoreCLR. A debug component is not installed.
[image: Error]

The error does not occur when I it to 6.0, but the error only occurs when I set it to 7.0. Running without debugs will work fine.

This bug didn't happen after the update, but it suddenly happened without any special reason. I've tried recovering and deleting and reinstalling completely, but I still get an error.

I'm using VS Community 2022 17.7.4 version.

Comment: Have you updated all the referenced package (winappsdk, winui3), deleted bin & obj directories and rebuilt?

Comment: Yes, I did, but it was the same. The 17.7.5 update that came out 10 minutes ago has solved it...

Comment: I'm not talking about Visual Studio

Comment: I know, I was just saying it was resolved with the update of vs2022.